# Ubuntu ошибка при запуске проекта Django

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

При запуске проекта(вк бот) выдаёт ошибку.

```
[11.05.2022 19:21:20 | INFO] [FreezingBot] Инициализация VK...
[11.05.2022 19:21:20 | INFO] [FreezingBot] запуск FREEZINGBOT (v.0.1)
BEA) ierens
[11.05.2022 19:21:20 | INFO] [FreezingBot] Этот сервер предназначен для обработки событий от VK!
[11.05.2022 19:21:20 | INFO] [FreezingBot] Запуск команд...
[11.05.2022 19:21:20 | ERROR] [FreezingBot] Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<VkBot.start() done, defined at /root/a
pp/bot/app.py:22> exception=SyntaxError('invalid syntax', ('<fstrin
g>', 1, 22, ‘(await number_to_emoji(num) )'))>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/app/bot/app.py", line 26, in start
await self.read_handlers()
File "/root/app/bot/app.py", line 197, in read_handlers
spec. loader .exec_module(module)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 674, in exec_
module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 781, in get_c
ode
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in sourc
e_to_code
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_fra
mes_removed
File "<fstring>", line 1
(await number_to_emoji(num) )
A

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 
 
 
 
 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDbGX.jpg

При запуске с Пк(windows) все отлично работает. Но при запуске с Ubuntu 18.04 он выдаёт ошибку.
```

Comment: Похоже вы используете питон версии <3.5. Там нет await-a.

Comment: Версия питона 3.6.9

Comment: А, тут await внутри f-string. Это поддерживается в питоне начиная с 3.7.